# What's the difference between querySelector() and getElementBy[Id/ClassName/TagName]?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid, queryselector

I don't get the difference between using querySelector() and, let's say, getElementById(). I understand that querySelector retrieves an element by using any selector, which makes it more versatile.

Are there any more differences? When should I use getElementById instead of querySelector?

Comment: This is really opinion based. Like I prefer to simply not use IDs at all. But others do use IDs. So for me, `querySelector` works best.

Comment: @imvain2 OP is in fact asking for differences, indicating they don't know if there are factual reasons to choose one over the other, depending on the situation. Performance in this case would be a factual reason to choose one over the other. Of course, there are tons of opinion based reasons as well, like readability. But I honestly don't consider this question a clear cut of "What's best to do?". More likely OP is looking if there are factual reasons or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://gomakethings.com/javascript-selector-performance/#:%7E:text=getElementById()%20can%20run%20about,runs%207%2C000%20operations%20a%20millisecond.):

> getElementById() can run about 15 million operations a second, compared to just 7 million per second for querySelector() in the latest version of Chrome.

So, if that amount of performance is important to you, it makes sense to do that. Otherwise, no, there is no difference other than the aforementioned flexibility.